# Sound doesn't work in user account but does in root

Tags: debian, audio

I have no sound under my user account but when I log into my root X account I do. `pavucontrol` works and the sound bar is moving when I play a sound but I have no sound. The port is named `Digital output`. The only thing that seems to differ between root and user is when I run `alsamixer`, under root the default opening pannel is `HDA Intel PCH`while under user it's `PulseAudio`, I can select HDA but only after going through the menu with `F6`